# How to update existing data and create new one django base command?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-commands

i am trying to store data in from json file and i added its not a problem to add data but when i trigger data again again they copy data and create same new one that i don't want , i want that it will update existing data and if there will new data in json file it will add in model .
here is my django base command code.

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
import requests
from demo.models import CoronaAge, CoronaSex, CoronaComorbidity

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        url = 'https://api.the2019ncov.com/api/fatality-rate'
        r = requests.get(url)
        titles = r.json()
        print(titles)

       # For between age
        for title in titles['byAge'] or []:
            CoronaAge.objects.update_or_create(
                age=title['age'],
                rate=title['rate']
            )

        context = {'titles': CoronaAge.objects.all()}

        # for sex wise male and female
        for title in titles['bySex'] or []:
            CoronaSex.objects.update_or_create(
                sex=title['sex'],
                rate=title['rate']
            )

        context = {'titles': CoronaSex.objects.all()}

        for title in titles['byComorbidity'] or []:
            CoronaComorbidity.objects.update_or_create(
                condition=title['preExistingCondition'],
                rate=title['rate']
            )

        context = {'titles': CoronaComorbidity.objects.all()}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would solve it. Get a list existing data. Then, for each new entry check if it exists in the db, create new object, add to list and at the end run bulk_create to insert all of them in one hit. If exists, then update all fields that you want and again, run bulk update at the end.

```
corona_ages = CoronaAge.objects.all()
new_ages = []
existing_ages = []
for title in titles['byAge'] or []:
    entry = corona_ages.filter(age=title['age']).first():
    if not entry:
        new_data = CoronaAge(**title)
        new_ages.append(new_data)
    else:
        entry['some_param'] = title['some_param']
        entry['other_param'] = title['other_param']
        existing_ages.append(new_date)

CoronaAge.objects.bulk_create(new_ages)
CoronaAge.objects.bulk_update(existing_ages)
```